# Ordered list numbering not working properly while pagination

Tags: php, html, pagination

I am using ordered list with php and its working fine and showing the numbers 1-10 correctly but in the next page its starting again from 1 for different list. I have tried some solutions found in this site, but not working. Given below is my code so far. Here `$startpoint =10;`

```
    <ol start="<?php echo $startpoint;?>">
        <li>
           <?php echo $objA->stringtag($question); ?>
         </li>
    </ol>
```

Comment: Did you check the value of start in the browser?

Comment: yes, and its showing correctly.

Comment: Your code is correct.  Where you define $startpoint =10; ?

Comment: So if start is correct, what is the problem? See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_ol_start) site for testing the start property.

Comment: In your file $startpoint value is not getting. So it's start always with 1...

Comment: @Pravin its defined in the header.

Comment: @Jeroen Its not working even when i tried manually `<ol start="10">`

Answer (score 0):

Try to something like this. I think in your File not getting `$startpoint` value. So, it's start with 1.

```
<?php $startpoint = 10; ?>
<ol start="<?php echo $startpoint;?>">
    <li><?php echo 'teastesest' ?> </li>
    <li><?php echo 'teastesest' ?> </li>
    <li><?php echo 'teastesest' ?> </li>
    <li><?php echo 'teastesest' ?> </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: If you have use this in .html file then it's not working. Please use .php file so it's working

Comment: hm tried in both extension as static and dynamic, but not working. I am using bootstrap for resonsive design.

Comment: Check Here it's working for .php  http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/chkc-yiya